# Multiple places at same location, wrong place displayed

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, google-places-api

I implemented a google map on my website to show my office location. In the same building there are multiple offices with the same address.

The problem is: The place description from another company (with the same address as mine) is displayed on my website. But I want to display my places description.

E.g.: Take a look at the following location:

`var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.137722, 11.577583)`

There are multiple doctors at this location.
The code at the bottom displays just the following:

[image]

but I want to display the following description (as I would google for Dr. Gallenberger) :
[image]

Hence: How to display my place on my map and hide another places?

Code:

```
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script>
  function initialize() {
    var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');
    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.137722, 11.577583)
    var mapOptions = {
      center: latLng,
      zoom: 17,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions)
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: latLng,
      map: map
    });
  }
  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

Comment: Did you add your company on google business?

Comment: I don't see any marker descriptions with the posted code.

Comment: yes the company is on google business, the posted code is just an example, there are no markers on that position (48.123456, 8.123456)

Comment: example improved with real example `var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.137722, 11.577583)`

Answer (score 0):

It's a little more complex than what you are doing but it should work if you get your placeID using this:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-placeid-finder

Then setup your request like shown here:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-details

If that doesn't work, try using the info windows feature to manually setup what is shown in that box:
https://
developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/infowindows

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but unfortunately this is not what I mean. I improved the example in my question, please check the question maybe its clearer now what I mean.